# Python: Combine two lists with nested while loops

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
Car = ["Audi", "Mercedes"]
Speed = [50, 100]
```

How can I achieve that the result I get is this:

```
['Audi 10', 'Mercedes 10', 'Audi 100', 'Mercedes 100']
```

Thanks

Comment: I assume it should be "Audi 50"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over both lists and use an f-string to get the desired output:

```
Car = ["Audi", "Mercedes"]
Speed = [50, 100]
print([f"{c} {s}" for s in Speed for c in Car])
```

Out:

```
['Audi 50', 'Mercedes 50', 'Audi 100', 'Mercedes 100']
```

Comment: This can fail if OP's python version is <3.6

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and f-strings:

```
result = [f'{c} {s}' for c, s in product(Car, Speed)]
# ['Audi 50', 'Audi 100', 'Mercedes 50', 'Mercedes 100']

result = [f'{c} {s}' for s, c in product(Speed, Car)]
# ['Audi 50', 'Mercedes 50', 'Audi 100', 'Mercedes 100']
```

Comment: Hello, that gives me: ['Audi 10', 'Audi 100', 'Mercedes 10', 'Mercedes 100'] but I really need it to be like this: ['Audi 10', 'Mercedes 10', 'Audi 100', 'Mercedes 100']

Comment: Then just turn it around: `... for s, c in product(Speed, Car)`

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. Unfortunately I cannot accept two answers as correct :/